# Symlinked folder not recognized by file_exists?

Tags: 7, files

A module I'm working on maintains a list of files in the private file system folder in Drupal. I use `hook_file_download` to control access to these files.

I generate links to these files, which end up like: `http://sample.com/system/files/my_folder/file.pdf`

My website path is `/var/www/sample.com/www` and the private folder path is configured to be `/var/www/sample.com/private`.

Now, if the file is placed is `/var/www/sample.com/private/my_folder/file.pdf`, everything works fine and I can properly control access to the file and deliver it. However, if `my_folder` is located elsewhere and symlinked in, then things break. I've tracked part of it down to the PHP function `file_exists` returning false, which is called in `file_download`.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Everything I've searched for thusfar indicates that symlinks should work just fine. The permissions on the symlinked directory are OK - the directory is 755 and the files are 644.

What else could this be?

I've tried this on the latest PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.4 with no difference.

**EDIT**: It's worth mentioning that I can get `file_exists` to return true if I pass the absolute path to the symlinked file. Drupal is passing a stream wrapper though (`private://my_folder/file.pdf`). So looks like it could be related to the streamwrapper somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept digging and found it was related to Drupal's stream wrapper implementation, specifically the `getLocalPath` method. There's already [a large Drupal issue for this](https://drupal.org/node/1008402), which I wouldn't have found with my previous search terms.